# Bizzare unresponsive Drupal jquery script

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I have a very simple jQuery script which partly works.

```
(function($) {
    console.log('Testing ...!');

    $('div').css('border', '2px solid red !important');
})(jQuery);
```

The console command successfully responds but the simple attempt to add a colored border to divs does **not** respond.

I am attaching the js script to Drupal via the following code:

```
function cse_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'cse') .'/scripts/autocomplete.js', 'file');
}
```

I have no idea why this rather simple script is not working as expected.

Comment: I have no experience in drupal development but if the console message is logged but the div is not bordered, then maybe it's some kind of a race condition. Maybe this can help you: https://coderwall.com/p/kd-4cg/javascript-jquery-and-dom-ready-in-drupal-7 . Your code is in an IIFE but does not ensure a ready state. You can try putting logic in a $(document).ready() or furthermore use the behaviour pattern described in the article.

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localised guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 0):

Your js is executing before the html is fully loaded, so it does not find any div. 2 solutions :

1. The jquery one : use a $(document).ready() like Samuil suggested.
2. The drupal one : use a behavior, you should take 5 mins to read this link to better understand how to use js in drupal : https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7